# Ionic 2 Warnings : [Bourbon][Deprecation]

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I run the cmd :

```
ionic serve
```

and my app runs perfectly. But I have something like 50 warnings on [Bourbon][Deprecation].The warnings are like this :

```
WARNING: [Bourbon] [Deprecation] `justify-content` is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0.0. We suggest using an autom
ated prefixing tool, like Autoprefixer.
Backtrace:
        node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon-deprecate.scss:10, in mixin `-bourbon-deprecate`
        node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/_bourbon-deprecate.scss:17, in mixin `-bourbon-deprecate-for-prefixi
ng`
        node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/css3/_flex-box.scss:239, in mixin `justify-content`
        src/theme/common/inputs/rating.scss:16, in mixin `rating-item-styles`
        src/pages/maps/maps.scss:213
```

So what is the problem? How to fix it?

I'm using ionic 2 angular 2

I have this :

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.2.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "1.1.7",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.26.2",
    "bourbon": "^4.3.3",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "ionic-native": "2.2.11",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
    "zone.js": "0.6.26"
  },
```

Comment: It basically says everything. You are using a method from the Bourbon library, that will be deprecated (removed) in coming versions. You must have installed Bourbon `npm install bourbon` at some point, and use `justify-content` somewhere in your code.

Comment: can you show your package.json in the question? you may have to update the `bourbon` library

Comment: @suraj I added the part ofdependencies

Comment: @TripTherapy hope my answer solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont actually require Bourbon with Ionic 2 as the default build stack [**here**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts#the-stack) uses [**Autoprefixer**](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts/blob/master/config/sass.config.js#L28).

If for any reason you are still using it, check the [changelog](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bourbon/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).All the mixins will be removed in version 5. For the current version, you can try:

```
$output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings: false;
@import "bourbon";
```

as mentioned [here](http://bourbon.io/docs/#output-bourbon-deprecation-warnings).

> If you choose not to upgrade, you can reduce pollution of your logs by
>   disabling the output of Bourbon’s deprecation-related Sass warnings.
>
> This variable must be declared before importing Bourbon.

Comment: I added the string to disable the output of Bourbon's deprecation-related Sassa warings,but I have only this string : autoprefixer: <css input>72217:3:You should write display:flex by final spec instead of display : block. It repeats 20 times..

Comment: probably some issue with the css. you might have to form a question with the scss part.